# How to split one row into two based on 2 different column values

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I am trying to accomplish something simple, but cant get to think straight. I have a case where 1 row can have different values in 2 different columns. But if thats the case then instead of displaying just 1 row for these 2 values, I need to display 2 rows for 1 column value each..for example.

```
  ID    Col1         col2  col3   col4              

46054   2011W3974   164505  1    2

58765   2014W3777   275908  1    NULL

52311   2013W1877   247047  1    NULL

63032   2015W3317   295279  1    NULL

57552   2014W2813   274810  1    NULL

44584   2011W2622   173985  1    2
```

This needs to be split into 2 rows for row 1 and 6 into 2 rows like below:

```
46054   2011W3974   164505  1    NULL
46054   2011W3974   164505  NULL 2
58765   2014W3777   275908  1   NULL
52311   2013W1877   247047  1   NULL
63032   2015W3317   295279  1   NULL
57552   2014W2813   274810  1   NULL
44584   2011W2622   173985  1   NULL
44584   2011W2622   173985  NULL 2
```

What is the best possible way to do this. I looked at SPLIT XML function, but I dont think that will be helpful here. I also played with ranking functions, but since this is 2 columns, I dont think that will work either. Please suggest

Thanks,
RV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd properly just union it together:

```
SELECT Id, Col1, Col2, Col3, NULL AS Col4
FROM <Your Table>
WHERE col4 is NULL

UNION

SELECT Id, Col1, Col2, NULL, Col4
FROM <Your Table>
WHERE Col4 = 2
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This works very well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Union not union All.

```
SELECT Id, Col1, Col2, Col3, NULL AS Col4
FROM YourTable
WHERE isnull(Col4 , 0) = 0

UNION

SELECT Id, Col1, Col2, NULL as Col3, Col4
FROM YourTable
WHERE isnull(Col3 , 0) = 0
```